# Publish Polymer component without Bower

Tags: package-managers, jspm

I would like to build and publish a component for use with Polymer.

While I have read the official article on [how to publish components with Bower](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/distributing-components-with-bower.html), I would rather like to distribute my component via GitHub/NPM. I expect the component to get installed via JSPM.

Since I have no experience in doing so, I wonder about a few issues:

- How can I make sure that the Polymer core is a dependency of my component and will get installed to the users project root if not already there? (As far as I can see Polymer is only available through bower or GitHub)
- Will JSPM detect whether there are any files (e.g `System.js` already installed and avoid duplication?
- Should I include tests & project code in the package?